# Как сделать чтобы менялся текст в кнопке с помощью css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Как сделать, чтобы менялся текст в кнопке после нажатия с '*Заказать*' на '*Успешно*'. И при нажатии на весь блок, текст в кнопках менялся обратно.

Знаю как сделать с помощью js, но надо сделать, чтобы в js-коде не было **кириллицы**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let $btn = $('button');

  $btn.click(function() {
    this.boolean = true;
    $(this).text("Успешно");
  });

  $('block').click(function(e) {
    let $this = $(this);

    if ($(e.target).closest($btn).length) {
      return;
    }
    $this.find($btn).prop("boolean", false);
    $this.find($btn).text("Заказать");
  });

});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 175px;
  display: inline-block;
  filter: grayscale(0%);
  transition: 1s;
  color: steelblue;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/223/200/150" alt="">text
  <button class="button">Button</button>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/222/200/150" alt="">text
  <button class="button">Button</button>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/225/200/150" alt="" /text <button class="button">Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: через `css` делать - это костыль. Почему нельзя в коде кириллицу?

Comment: @ThisMan такое условие

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Итить-колотить...

А чем свойство `content` не устраивает?

```css
.click_me:before {
  content: 'Нажми меня';
}

.clicked:before {
  content: 'Нажато!';
}
```

```html
<button class="click_me" onclick="this.className='clicked'"></button>
```

И всго-то делов...

Answer (score 1):

На чистом css можно сделать, чтобы текст менялся туда и обратно при нажатии на кнопку. Менять текст ещё и при нажатии на весь блок без js едва ли получится.

```css
.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 175px;
  display: inline-block;
  filter: grayscale(0%);
  transition: 1s;
  color: steelblue;
  font-size: 30px;
}
input {
  display: none;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
label:after {
  content: 'заказать';
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
}
input:checked ~ label {
  background-color: green;
}
input:checked ~ label:after {
  content: 'успешно';
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/223/200/150" alt="">text
  <input type="checkbox" id="one" />
  <label for="one"></label>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/222/200/150" alt="">text
  <input type="checkbox" id="two" />
  <label for="two"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Пока ходил посуду мыть, понял что можно сделать так

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let $btn = $('button');
  let $order = $('order');
  let $suc = $('suc');

  $btn.click(function() {
    this.boolean = true;
    $(this).find($order).css("display", "none");
    $(this).find($suc).css("display", "inline");

  });

  $('block').click(function(e) {
    let $this = $(this);

    if ($(e.target).closest($btn).length) {
      return;
    }
    $this.find($btn).prop("boolean", false);
    $(this).find($order).css("display", "inline");
    $(this).find($suc).css("display", "none");
  });

});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 175px;
  display: inline-block;
  filter: grayscale(0%);
  transition: 1s;
  color: steelblue;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.suc {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/223/200/150" alt="">text
  <button class="button">
    <p class="order">Заказать</p>
    <p class="suc">Успешно</p>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/222/200/150" alt="">text
  <button class="button">
    <p class="order">Заказать</p>
    <p class="suc">Успешно</p>
  </button
</div>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/225/200/150" alt="" />text 
  <button class="button">
    <p class="order">Заказать</p>
    <p class="suc">Успешно</p>
  </button
</div>
```

Comment: так не работает же